# Shutdown init script is not executing on immediate reboot on CentOS 7.1

Tags: centos, init-script, chkconfig

I have installed an init script to run on system shutdown with the following command

```
/sbin/chkconfig --add shutdownExample
```

My shutdownExample(custom script to run at system shutdown) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 35 99 01
# description: custom shutdown script
# lockfile: /var/lock/subsys/shutdownExample

start() {
    # touch /var/lock/subsys/filename
    touch /var/lock/subsys/shutdownExample
 }

stop() {

    echo "Commands executed successfully at " >> shutdown.txt

    #some important stuff goes here

    rm -rf /var/lock/subsys/shutdownExample
}

case "$1" in
start)
start
;;
stop)
stop
;;

*)
echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
RETVAL=1
esac

exit 0
```

My need is to execute `shutdownExample` script on system shutdown. It should create a file `shutdown.txt`.

Now the problem: After the daemon installation, if I shutdown the system once, K** scripts are not receiving `stop` argument. From the second restart onwards, init script is executing fine. Why my `shutdownExample` is not being executed on immediate restart? Any help appreciated

Comment: I think CentOS 7 uses systemd.

Comment: oh!! really? is `chkconfig` replaced with `systemd`? But with `chkconfig`, my init script is executing fine from the second reboot

Comment: It is not replaced. May be you did no start the service. chkconfig does not start it.

Comment: No, I have tried executing `service shutdownExample start`. service started successfully. But on shutdown it is not being stopped automatically